# Firebase Analytics Error - Operation failed - Error code 2

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have integrated firebase analytics with my android app. Now firebase data is transferred to bigquery for daily usage.

In Bigquery, I can see the sporadic occurrence of this firebase autogenerated event with event_dim_name='error' and inside event_dim_params_key, firebase_event_origin has value 'auto'  and firebase_error has int value 2.

I have tried searching in Firebase doc to see that might be the reason behind this sporadically occurring error.
Official doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.FirebaseError#code
This hardly gave any useful insight.

Old firebase doc: https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/FirebaseError.html#OPERATION_FAILED

Says the operation failed 
(after cross checking possible error code value from here https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.firebase.client.FirebaseError.OPERATION_FAILED)

Can anybody guide me as to how to find the reason behind the failure ?

PS: I have tried observing the terminal log of firebase. But this error is hard to generate. I got the error events from production.

Comment: I doubt that this has nothing to do with your code and it's Firebase' own error, to sync data with cloud from/to device.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a firebase analytics error code: invalid event name.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors

Most likely you're logging a custom event with a name that's too long (especially if you're using a pre-v8 version of the SDK) or includes non-alphanumeric characters (such as space, hyphen, or parentheses), or doesn't start with a letter.

Comment: In my case spaces